# Date script for Dropdown using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to populate dropdown/ select list with calender dates in DD-MM-YYYY format, I have to do this in JavaScript and script should automatically fill Dropdown with dates for next 3 months.

I tried to look for such script but could not find. I would appreciate any help. i am open to use any jQuery if it works.

I have to fill dropdown with date in the format mentioned i cant use popup Calenders etc..

Example:

```
<select class="ddDates" id="Dates" name="Dates">
    <option value="10-01-2012" selected>10-01-2012</option>
    <option value="11-01-2012">11-01-2012</option>
    <option value="12-01-2012">12-01-2012</option>
    <option value="13-01-2012">13-01-2012</option>
</select>
```

I have searched google and i cant even find the logic how i can read system calender and populate the dropdown/ select list

Comment: i think you need to Google a little to find some logic for generating calender.. then you try displaying it as you want. try out some working stuff then will help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code generates the markup in question using JavaScript (and jQuery)

```
function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
var date = new Date();
var selectElement = $('<select>'), optionElement;
for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
    optionElement = $('<option>')
    optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
    optionElement.text(formattedDate);
    selectElement.append(optionElement);
}
```

You can change the value of `count` according to your logic.

Comment: I tried to call the function but it does not show anything <script type="text/javascript"> pad(2) </script>. I am doing something wrong

Comment: See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/saQTw/ (pad just adds leading zero to single digit numbers, check the code :) )

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI's Datepicker:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I was thinking the same, but `i cant use popup Calenders etc` in the question means this may not be suitable for the OP.

Comment: That is not a popup, that is a Dropdown, just like OP asked.

Comment: I took dropdown to mean filling a native HTML select box - hence my first comment. Without clarification from the OP it's hard to tell exactly what he wants. This is the best solution though IMO.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Perhaps some input from OP would clear this up.

Comment: I need to fi1l select box with dates of next 2 or 3 months based on the current system date.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I took the same meaning, hence is the solution I provided. Though, I also don't think giving dates of 3 months in a select box can be nice idea anywhere.